# how do i make a select box populate div on change

Tags: php, jquery

so, I have read just about every question on this subject, but the solutions don't work for my project, it seems that when I change the dropdown, it does the first event, but when I change to a different element it doesn't do anything else, but when I do this with an alert message it changes every time.

here is what I have to demonstrate what I mean

I tried .post it works great until I add php and all the dynamic functions, is it because I used $('#updateDiv').html(url);

I also hide and showed the div based on the change of the dropdown, but all that did was hid and show the div, I want the div to show the content based on a list of categories.

the PHP side will be dynamic, but if I do .html() none of the php renders properly.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/LrxUS/

Comment: You want to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) maybe?

Comment: you can use $.get("YOUR_URL"); to load content in the div...
Reference : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: This actually sounds like the element gets replaced so the event handler is no longer attached to said element. Simply put, `$(document).on('change', mydropdown, function(){ //stuff });` should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.post(url, function(data) {
    $("#updateDiv").html(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks eggplant, that is what I used the first time, I loaded a page called categories.php and it loaded in different tables based on the selected option in the drop down, however it did not render any dynamic php right, for instance I had custom functions from wordpress and it ignored them all, causing file not found errors or variable not found errors.

Comment: If you got any php error, it means the php code is being actually executed. Now you have to fix those errors. If you just type the URL of this php file in your browser, what do you get?

Comment: Well I would get nothing as it's an included file, if I where to use this file with no jquery, it would be required into the div. also when I required the file it didn't cause any errors.

Comment: What does it mean "I would get nothing as it's an included file"? Of course you would get something, as it's a php file! Maybe it needs some parameters to be correctly executed, but a php file is a php file.

Comment: hahaha well I would get the tables, but since how I am working in wordpress if I went to the url manually none of the wordpress functions will be loaded in there, the $_POST['name'] variable works on the categories page tho.

Comment: Ok, so what do you expect from here? You could for example read WHAT errors the script gives, and what parameters it expects.

Comment: maybe I should post this with a wordpress tag, since all the errors are wordpress related? well i would say all the errors are php anyway, it seems all of wordpress's functionality is gone when I call the load function, raw php works fine in this file.

Answer (score 0):

As per the fiddle, you have specified

```
var mydropdown = $('#mydropdown');
```

but in the change function, you have specified $(mydropdown), either define only id in the variable or the object. Like,

```
var mydropdown = '#mydropdown';
$(mydropdown).change(function() {}
```

After that use $.ajax to get the dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets make it the simplest so that there is no room for mistake in the client side script. Use $.load method defined [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

AS:

```
$("#updateDiv").load(url);
```

And don't forget to check what your firebug, chrome inspector or fiddler says about your request in case if you don't get the required result.